# is it correct to apply transaction atomic inside form?

Tags: django, forms, transactions, save, atomic

I have a `ModelForm` where I want to override save() method to create related objects. I need that in `transaction.atomic()`

is it correct to apply it like this :

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self, commit):
         self.instance.save()
         # and create related objects using self.instance..
```

Cause I've always seen that it is applied on the view, but my view is class based so I can't apply this decorator. and it also seems logical to me to apply it in the actual method which does the saves.
Second, what is the 'depth' of the transaction atomic, if I apply it to view, I guess it apply to any call from there?

Comment: You can use that decorator with any function, however, you can also achieve this inside the view, it doesn't matter if it's classed based or not. You can also create the related objects within the view so you don't have to modify the modelForm. What is your view looks like, why can't you use it there? (I added an example below, for classed based views)

Comment: my view is a generic one, so I figured I should used method_decorator. I think it is more logical to do save work in the form rather than in view?

Comment: if you want to use decorator and have the ability to handle integrity errors too, then consider using both. You can do this inside the form, it's up to you. If it requires you to pass new arguments to form init, then it may be better to do inside the view.

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment, I'm adding an example of how to do this within a class based view.

You can use a decorator like this:

```
class YourView(View):
    @transaction.atomic
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

Or better you can do this:

```
class YourView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                your_model = form.save()
                generate_relationships()
        except IntegrityError:
            handle_exception()
```

Or you can use both.

Reference: [django transactions docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic)